# How to find the width of single cell in xaxis ? ( Refer screenshot )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

I am new to charts and I have a question: how do I find the width of a single cell in the x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract that information from xAxis object, by translationSlope param.

```
chart.xAxis[0].translationSlope
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y5Lob9f3/